# Java: What/where are the maximum and minimum values of a GregorianCalendar?

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

What are the maximum and minimum values of a GregorianCalendar?

Are they in a constant like Integer.MAX_VALUE, or maybe GregorianCalendar.get(BLAH)?

In a nutshell, how can I create a GregorianCalendar instance with min/max value?

Comment: For new readers to this question I recommend you don’t use `GregorianCalendar`. It was a mostly failed attempt to make up for the problems with `Date`. Use `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
GregorianCalendar maxgc = new GregorianCalendar();
maxgc.setTime(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE));

GregorianCalendar mingc = new GregorianCalendar();
mingc.setTime(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution doesn't work. After mingc.setTime(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)) you get: migc.get(Calendar.YEAR) == 292269055 or sth like this. That doesn't sound like a min to me:-).

Comment: Thank you =D

I'm only using these values for comparison so I'm fine, but for others this may be worthy of mention.

From setTime() documentation:
Note: Calling setTime() with Date(Long.MAX_VALUE) or Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)  may yield incorrect field values from get().

Comment: pajton, check this:

<code>migc.get(Calendar.ERA)</code>

0 means BC
1 means AD

So year 292269055 corresponds to 292269055 BC

Comment: Right. This is quite clever actually;-)

Comment: Better use `new Date(0)` for minimum date.

Comment: The reason i searched, is that the Date is deprecated, and yet we use Date to set Calendar? :|

Comment: @WaelJ i get positive value that had some truncated 0 at end for long min, and i checked js supported date time, i change from -9........L to -8.........L still got that error, it is positive and unsupported by JS

Answer (score 5):

I took joekutner's suggestion and ran it with:

```
GregorianCalendar gCal = new GregorianCalendar( );

gCal.setTime(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
System.out.println( "Min Date is " + gCal.getTime() + " " + gCal.get(Calendar.ERA));

gCal.set( Calendar.SECOND, 3 );
System.out.println( "Min Date less 1 second is " + gCal.getTime() + " " + gCal.get(Calendar.ERA));

gCal.setTime(new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE));
System.out.println( "Max Date is " + gCal.getTime() + " " + gCal.get(Calendar.ERA));


Min Date is Sun Dec 02 16:47:04 GMT 292269055 0
Min Date less 1 second is Sun Aug 17 07:12:54 GMT 292278994 1
Max Date is Sun Aug 17 07:12:55 GMT 292278994 1
```

Which shows the minimum and maximum, and between them an indication of what happens if you try to move to the second before the minimum - you wrap around.

This was version 1.6.0_17.

Answer (score 3):

---

You can try to call [Calendar.getMinimum()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getMinimum%28int%29) for each type of field (i.e. year, month, etc.) and then set those minimum values on corresponding field types. This would give you the minimum calendar. I don't know if there is a faster way to do that.

Comment: I don’t think it will give you the expected result (have not tried). There are dependencies between those fields.

Answer (score 2):

The other Answers may be correct but use outmoded classes.

## java.time

The old date-time classes (java.util.Date/.Calendar etc.) have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

The java.time classes are inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), extended by the ThreeTen-Extra project, back-ported to Java 6 & 7 by the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

For a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), use [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). Given an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), use [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). For a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) (offset + rules for anomalies), use [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), but by its nature has no defined min/max, nor does [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html). For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). For a time-of-day only value without date and without time zone, use [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). For date-time without time zone, use [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

The following are all pre-defined constants.

- [`Instant.MIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#MIN) = `-1000000000-01-01T00:00Z`
  [`Instant.MAX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#MAX) = `1000000000-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z`
- [`OffsetDateTime.MIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#MIN) = `-999999999-01-01T00:00:00+18:00`
  [`OffsetDateTime.MAX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#MAX) = `+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999-18:00`
- [`LocalDate.MIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#MIN) = `-999999999-01-01`
  [`LocalDate.MAX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#MAX) = `+999999999-12-31`
- [`LocalTime.MIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MIN) = `00:00`
  [`LocalTime.MAX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MAX) = `23:59:59.999999999`
- [`LocalDateTime.MIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#MIN) = `-999999999-01-01T00:00:00`
  [`LocalDateTime.MAX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#MAX) = `+999999999-12-31T23:59:59.999999999`
- [`Year.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#MIN_VALUE) = `-999,999,999`
  [`Year.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#MAX_VALUE) = `+999,999,999`
- [`ZoneOffset.MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#MIN) = `-18:00` (but `-12:00` in practice)
  [`ZoneOffset.MAX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#MAX) = `+18:00` (but `+14:00` in practice)

**Caution:** Be wary of using these values as some kind of flag or special meaning. Many other software libraries and databases may not support these extreme values.

For a flag or special meaning such as a non-null "no value available", I suggest picking an arbitrary moment but avoid going to such extreme reaches either backward or forward in time. Perhaps the [Unix epoch reference date](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)), the first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Defined as a constant in Java: [Instant.EPOCH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#EPOCH)

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).