# Minimum date in Java

Tags: java, date

What is the minimum date value in Java?

Comment: What does the minimum date mean ?

Comment: See this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393016/java-what-where-are-the-maximum-and-minimum-values-of-a-gregoriancalendar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: What/where are the maximum and minimum values of a GregorianCalendar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393016/java-what-where-are-the-maximum-and-minimum-values-of-a-gregoriancalendar)

Comment: @qrtt1 the Big Bang of course. Unless you happen to be very good at mathematics and meta-physics.

Answer (score 86):

Don't forget that Date constructor happily accepts negative values.

```
Date date = new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE);
```

returns

> Sun Dec 02 22:47:04 BDT 292269055

I guess that's about the time of <s>Big Bang</s> dinosaurs :)

**EDIT**

As *martin clayton* answered, you can use the Calendar class to check the era. This will output 0 which stands for BCE:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.ERA));
```

Comment: But this seems to be a date in the future (year 292269055), not in the past. Seems that the parameter is being interpreted as a positive value.

Comment: @Grodriguez - what's the era on that year though? ;-)

Comment: @tulskiy, Andrzej: Right! Sorry :)

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: what else is there in standard java to use instead of the Calendar?

Comment: @tulskiy, not much.  Hence use JODA .

Comment: It's about 300 million BCE, not quite the big bang ;)

Comment: @Adam: yeah, it's about the time of dinosaurs, I was just too lazy to edit the answer :)

Comment: Hahahah the time of Big Bang and dinossaurs just made my day :D

Comment: so the first day of the java was a holiday. Pretty lazy language :)

Answer (score 49):

If you are talking about `java.util.Date` as a timestamp you can do this

`Date d = new Date(0L)` and you will see this represents Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 GMT 1970

---

As [tulskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143585/tulskiy) has pointed out it is possible to pass a negative value to the Date constructor. If we do this and use a date format that includes the era we can see:

```
Date d = new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE);
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy G HH:mm:ss Z");
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

displays: Sun, 2 Dec 292269055 BC 16:47:04 +0000

Answer (score 19):

The other Answers may be correct but use outmoded classes.

## java.time

The old date-time classes (java.util.Date/.Calendar etc.) have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

The java.time classes are inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), extended by the ThreeTen-Extra project, back-ported to Java 6 & 7 by the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

For a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), use [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). Given an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), use [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). For a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) (offset + rules for anomalies), use [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), but by its nature has no defined minimum, nor does [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html). For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). For a time-of-day only value without date and without time zone, use [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html). For date-time without time zone, use [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

- [`Instant.MIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#MIN) = `-1000000000-01-01T00:00Z`
- [`OffsetDateTime.MIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#MIN) = `-999999999-01-01T00:00:00+18:00`
- [`LocalDate.MIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#MIN) = `-999999999-01-01`
- [`LocalTime.MIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MIN) = `00:00`
- [`LocalDateTime.MIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#MIN) = `-999999999-01-01T00:00:00`
- [`Year.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html#MIN_VALUE) = `-999,999,999`
- [`ZoneOffset.MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#MIN) = `-18:00` (but `-12:00` in practice)

**Caution:** Be wary of using these values as some kind of flag or special meaning. Many other software libraries and databases may not support these extreme values.

For a flag or special meaning such as a non-null "no value available", I suggest picking an arbitrary moment but avoid going to such extreme reaches either backward or forward in time. Perhaps the [Unix epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), the first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Defined as a constant in Java: [Instant.EPOCH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#EPOCH)

Answer (score 5):

It's the same as for the Calendar classes.

Try this:

```
Date d = new Date( Long.MIN_VALUE );
System.out.println( d );
```

You'll see:

```
Sun Dec 02 16:47:04 GMT 292269055
```

But the default date format doesn't include the era - which is **BCE** for this date.

Answer (score 1):

LocalDateTime MIN defines the minimum supported LocalDateTime, '-999999999-01-01T00:00:00'.
This is the local date-time of midnight at the start of the minimum date.

public static final LocalDateTime MIN; this is the MIN syntax;

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime a = LocalDateTime.MIN;

    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```