# Min/Max Date/DateTime in JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime

Is there any way in JodaTime to construct a Date/DateTime which will always be smaller/larger than any other Date/DateTime? Something along the lines of

```
DateTime bigBang = DateTime.xxx();
DateTime endOfUniverse = DateTime.yyy();
```

Constraint: I don't want to use the standard Java Date libraries.

Comment: I think `new DateTime(0)` will give you the minimum `DateTime` that can be represented. Just a wild guess, but maybe the max value of `long` would be the maximum?

Comment: With Java 8, it is simply [`LocalDateTime.MAX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#MAX) (resp. MIN)

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis 0 would give 01/01/1970. You can definitely go further in the past with negative values. MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE are not valid values for DateTime, though. They're OK for Instant.

Comment: IMO, Joda was not meant to be used this way. I found a method `BasicChronology.getMaxYears()` but this is a package method.

Comment: @Tunaki I agree. In addition to`Chronology` issue there is also a `TimeZone` issue. When maxDate is created and it has to be converted to different time zone (which involves adding hours) the result could be buggy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## java.time

The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. The team advises migration to the java.time classes.

For min/max in java.time, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36488041/642706) on a similar Question.

## Joda-Time

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) tracks time as a count of [milliseconds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) since the epoch of first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). This count is kept using a [64-bit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) `long` integer. So, technically, the maximum and minimums are the +/- limits of a `long`.

```
… new DateTime( Long.MIN_VALUE )
… new DateTime( Long.MAX_VALUE )
```

Joda-Time has no such minimum/maximum values available conveniently as constants. In contrast, note that Joda-Time’s successor, [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 and later, does indeed offer the constants [`LocalDateTime.MIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#MIN) and [`LocalDateTime.MAX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#MAX).

By the way, the Joda-Time team has advised we should migrate to java.time. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), further adapted to Android in [ThreeTen-ABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## Too big, too small

**Beware of these extremes.** Their use is not practical. Various libraries, apps, databases, and other sinks/sources of date-time values may have much different limits, some much larger but typically much smaller.

For example, many systems use the old tradition from UNIX & POSIX of tracking time as a 32-bit integer count of whole seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. The natural limit of +/- two billion seconds results in the looming [Year 2038 Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Another limit is the physical display size of fields on forms and reports that expect only four digits in a year number.

## Workaround

You can define your own min/max.

You may want extreme values such as year 0000 and year 9999. Joda-Time supports years later than 9,999 but I would stick with 4 digits to fit the commonly used formats for display on-screen and in reports. Visually, the four nines stand out as a bogus date.

Or you may want an expected minimum value appropriate to your business logic. If building a new invoicing system, then you know the year should always be this year or later.

I suggest defining constants on a helper class. Something like this:

```java
package com.example;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

public class JodaTimeHelper {

    static final public DateTime START_OF_TIME = new DateTime( 0000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC );
    static final public DateTime END_OF_TIME = new DateTime( 9999, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC );

    static final public DateTime MINIMUM_INVOICE_DATETIME = new DateTime( 2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC );

}
```

Here is the syntax for calling those constants.

```java
System.out.println( "START_OF_TIME: " + JodaTimeHelper.START_OF_TIME );
System.out.println( "END_OF_TIME: " + JodaTimeHelper.END_OF_TIME );
System.out.println( "MINIMUM_INVOICE_DATETIME: " + JodaTimeHelper. MINIMUM_INVOICE_DATETIME );
```

When run.

```
START_OF_TIME: 0000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
END_OF_TIME: 9999-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
MINIMUM_INVOICE_DATETIME: 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Just a side note, the extreme min/max dates supported by JodaTime would be:

new DateTime(Long.MIN_VALUE);
new DateTime(Long.MAX_VALUE);

Answer (score 2):

When all dates are within the same TimeZone, you can create `DateTime` object with fields assigned to minimum or max value.
However when using this constructor

```
DateTime(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour, int secondOfMinute)
```

with `Years.MAX_VALUE.getYears()` I have below exception:

[image]

So using the max number of years from exception, I have came up with the following end-of-universe dateTime:

```
DateTime dtMax = new DateTime(292278993, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59);
System.out.println(dtMax);
// prints 292278993-12-31T23:59:59
```

See [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) for more details.
Also an interesting discussion can be read [here](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/138).

Comment: This depends on the Chronology used. In the CopticChronology, the max years is 292272708

Comment: ISOChronology is used in above example.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through lots of different tangents on this, I finally decided to figure out a minimal case that works for both the minimum and maximum for the UTC time zone. And it turns out that attempting to use `Long`'s `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE` send me down rabbit trails.

So, given the following code snippet:

```
new DateTime(milliseconds, DateTimeZone.UTC)
```

here are the minimum/maximum values that work for `milliseconds` (tested in Java 1.7):

```
UTC_DATE_TIME_MIN_VALUE_IN_MILLIS = 9223372017129599999L
UTC_DATE_TIME_MAX_VALUE_IN_MILLIS = -9223372017043200000L
```

Both of these values are approximately 20 billion away from `Long.MIN_VALUE` and `Long.MAX_Value`.