# Java Calendar/Date Minvalue Supported on DB/Rest

Tags: java, sql, date, calendar, hsqldb

I'm using Spring Boot, and HSQLDB file, 
When i use:

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(-9223372036854775808L);
calendar.setTime(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));
```

and and store the model,

after i call rest client, i get invalid date, when i check it, it returns some positive value instead of negative one :| what should i use as min_Value.

i thought it may be SQL issue, i changed temporary variable type from timespan to Date, but didn't worked again, i no longer sure what is the case of this issue, and what nuber i should use, every one talk about min value, some one talked about around -8.......L too that work in JS, but it didn't worked here too :|

Comment: in SQL-92, year has to be between -9999 and 9999. Just pick a random date in the past as min value (1st Jan of year 1? 1st Jan -9999 ?). Note that depending on the exact column type and database, the valid range may be more restricted. You may also consider using NULL if you want to represent a non existing value.

Comment: @assylias SQL-92 year has to be between 1 and 9999. In Java, dates before 1970-01-01 have negative millisecond values.

Comment: @assylias it didn't worked...

Comment: @deadManN try using 0L for 1970-01-01 as minimum value

Comment: @fredt true, that work, i done it before i ask, but that's not the minimum value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Avoid ancient date-time values

Many reasons to not use that minimum number as a date value. As commented, standard SQL does not permit such ancient dates. No database implementation I know of supports that value. And using a date-time for historical values is fraught with problems and issues, and ill-advised.

## Use epoch as a flag value

If you are looking for an arbitrary value to use as a flag such as "no value intended" while avoiding the use of nulls, then I suggest using the Java and [Unix epoch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) of first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). If you know your system will never store any date-time that far back as a valid value, this will work well. And `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` is easily recognized by many programmers, DBAs, and SysAdmins as the common epoch and therefore likely to be a special value.

## java.time

Avoid using the `Date` and `Calendar` classes. These troublesome classes and their siblings are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

These classes include a constant for that epoch value: [`Instant.EPOCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#EPOCH)

Similar Question: [Minimum date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3838242/642706)