# Java equivalent of .NET DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.Today

Tags: java, datetime, date

Is there a Java equivalent of DateTime.MinValue and DateTime.Today in the Java Date class? Or a way of achieving something similar?

I've realised how spoilt you are with the .NET datetime class, I also need the equivalent of AddDays(), AddMonths().

Comment: See also, [Java: What/where are the maximum and minimum values of a GregorianCalendar?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2393016/642706).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The de-facto Java datetime API is [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

With it, you can get the current date/time by just constructing `new DateTime()`.

Similarly, Without it, you can use `Calendar.getInstance()` or `new Date()` to obtain the current date/time.

`MinValue` can be `Calendar.getInstance(0)` / `new Date(0)`. This would use the default chronology - i.e. since January 1st, 1970. Since `MinValue` returns Januar 1st, year 1, you can do that be simply specifying this date, using the appropriate constructor of `DateTime`.

Comment: +1. Java built in dates are bad. Take the 3 extra seconds to build around Joda time, and you will be much happier.

Comment: I've heard of Jon Skeet's api, but is this android friendly?

Comment: I believe it is completely android-friendly. (Jon Skeet has made a port of JodaTime to .NET (noda-time))

Comment: I thought Joda time was his not Noda time, I'll give it a try

Comment: I could just use the epoch as the min value (I'm looking for something to indicate no date has been set), I'm not so sure about the opposite though

Comment: For no date set you could use a date of "null". Means you have to null check it more, but null is a better description for no date set, then some random date (-764 B.C. or such )

Comment: From [Joda-Time's web-site](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/): **"Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project."** Also joda-time is limited to millisecond precision.

Answer (score 4):

The other Answers may be correct but use outmoded classes.

## java.time

The old date-time classes (java.util.Date/.Calendar etc.) were supplanted by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), which in turn has been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. The java.time classes are inspired by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), extended by the ThreeTen-Extra project, back-ported to Java 6 & 7 by the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

To get the current moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), use [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

`Instant` has three constants:

- [`EPOCH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#EPOCH) – `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`
- [`MIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#MIN) – `-1000000000-01-01T00:00Z`
- [`MAX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#MAX) – `1000000000-12-31T23:59:59.999999999Z`

To get the current moment for an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), apply a [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) to get an [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.of( "-04:00" ) );
```

Better to apply a [full time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (offset plus rules for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time) if known. Apply a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

You can perform arithmetic.

```
ZonedDateTime dayLater = now.plusDays( 1 );
ZonedDateTime monthLater = now.plusMonths( 1 );
```

You can get the first moment of a day.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime tomorrowStart = now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( zoneId );  // Usually time-of-day of `00:00:00.0` but not always.
```

If you need only a date without time-of-day and without time zone, use [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). Similarly, [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) for time-only without date and without time zone. Usually better to stick with `Instant` and `OffsetDateTime`/`ZonedDateTime` as the `Local…` types do not represent actual moments on the timeline (no offset or time zone means they are undefined).

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.now( zoneId );
```

Comment: The first question is still unanswered here

Answer (score 3):

### Comparison of Date/Time features in .NET and Java

| .NET DateTime (C#) | Joda DateTime (Java, deprecated) [See Note #2] | Java Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [DateTime.MinValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue) | new DateTime(Long.MIN_VALUE) | new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE) [See Note #3] |
| [DateTime.Today](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today) | new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay() | Messy [See Note #4] |
| [DateTime.Now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now) | new DateTime() | new Date() |
| [DateTime.MaxValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.maxvalue) | new DateTime(Long.MAX_VALUE) | new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE) |

Additional notes:

1. Dealing with dates and times is messy. This table is intended to be a starting point for code migrations. The comparisons compare concepts, not exact values (e.g. .NET's minimum date/time is not the same value as Java's)
2. [Joda DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24631909/3063884) is the preferred date/time library for Java.
3. See [additional notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838384/3063884) on `new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE)` in Java
4. Getting start of day with Java's Date is a little more involved - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308356/how-to-obtain-the-start-time-and-end-time-of-a-day).
5. .NET DateTimes default to local date/time, whereas in Java they default to UTC. Make sure to consider any [impact of timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result) when working with dates and times.

### Joda-Time Deprecated

Joda-Time is deprecated. From their [web-site](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) <sup>[archive](https://archive.ph/xnzvm)</sup>:

> **Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.**

Meaning that <kbd><strike>java.util.Date</strike></kbd> → <kbd><strike>org.joda.time.DateTime</strike></kbd> → <kbd>java.time.ZonedDateTime</kbd>

Giving us new mappings:

| .NET DateTime (C#) | java.time (formerly known as Joda-Time) | Java Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [DateTime.MinValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue) | [LocalDateTime.MIN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#MIN) | new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE) |
| [DateTime.Today](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today) | [LocalDateTime.of](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalTime-)([LocalDate.NOW](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#now--), [LocalTime.MIDNIGHT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MIDNIGHT)) | (not available) |
| [DateTime.Now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now) | [LocalDateTime.now()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now--) | new Date() |
| [DateTime.UtcNow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow) | [LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC) | (not available) |
| [DateTime.MaxValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.maxvalue) | [LocalDateTime.MAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#MAX) | new Date(Long.MAX_VALUE) |

The .NET `DateTime` contains:

- date
- time
- and no particular information about what timezone it contains (except to day "Local", "UTC", or "Unspecified").

This means the `java.time` equivalent is `LocalDateTime`. If you want a datetime object that also carries with it an offset from UTC:

- **.NET**: `DateTimeOffset`
- **`java.time`**: `ZonedDateTime`

Answer (score -2):

Most date manipulation should be done using the Calendar object now.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: this doesn't answer his question.

Comment: @Bozho, as Chris has understood I was attempting to point him in the right direction for date manipulation with core Java.

Comment: I didn't think it was Bozho, I've read enough of your answers that you don't strike me as that petty. I admit the answer could have had much more detail but I didn't really have time.

Answer (score -2):

to get the current date:

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

```
    try {

        System.out.println("Today: " + dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Theres calendar
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

And date
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Theres also simpledateformat for formatting.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html