# Apache Axis - Calendar instance that gets serialized to 0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

Tags: java, .net, xsd, calendar, axis

I'm using Apache Axis to communicate with a web service written in .Net.

One of the functions in that WS has special handling when it encounters `DateTime.MinDate` (i.e. "0001-01-01"). Now, I'm trying to send this special value to the WS, but there seems to be no equivalent to `DateTime.MinDate` in Java.

As you probably know, Axis wraps `xsd:dateTime` into `Calendar` objects, so I tried sending `new GregorianCalendar(1 ,1 ,1);` but this didn't do the trick. I tried `calendar.setTime(new Date(0))`, I tried many more combinations, but nothing seems to get serialized as

`<endDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</endDate>`

which is what I need. Does anyone have any clue how can this be achieved?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006186/java-equivalent-of-datetime-minvalue-datetime-today

Comment: Seen it, but it's not really that similar... That one asks for a Java equivalent in general, which I know how to get (new GregorianCalendar(1 ,1 ,1);), but I need something that will be serialized to SOAP xsd:dateTime in the same way as DateTime.MinDate (i.e. 0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z) which the afore mentioned solution doesn't seem to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will create a GregorianCalendar object that will serialize to the equivalent
of `DateTime.MinValue`.

```
GregorianCalendar gc=new GregorianCalendar(1,0,1);
gc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-0"));
```

Note the following:

- The month parameter is zero based, not 1 based.
- GregorianCalendar defaults to the local time zone, therefore the timezone needs
    to be adjusted manually.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a bunch! I was so close but couldn't have done it without your help.