# Correct way to parse an xsd:date to LocalDate

Tags: java, xml

When googling this, I came across many answers - hence the question.

What is the *correct* way to parse *any* `xsd:date` to a `LocalDate` in Java?

Here are the ways I have come up with (from googling):

```
DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
    .newXMLGregorianCalendar(str)
    .toGregorianCalendar()
    .toZonedDateTime()
    .toLocalDate()
```

Another:

```
DatatypeConverter.parseDate(str)
    .toInstant()
    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    .toLocalDate()
```

Or perhaps I should be doing something different altogether?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519800/apache-axis-calendar-instance-that-gets-serialized-to-0001-01-01t000000-000z

Comment: @kaqqao - I don't believe it does...

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to *correctly* convert *any* `xsd:date` to `LocalDate`.

Because `xsd:date` may have timezone and `LocalDate` does not have timezone. So either it's not *any* `xsd:date` or the conversion is not entirely *correct*.

If you're OK with losing timezone then I'd just do:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar cal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(str);
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of(cal.getYear(), cal.getMonth(), cal.getDay());
```

I've seen a couple of answers which do this via `GregorianCalendar` and `ZonedDateTime`, but I don't understand why have this indirection if you're up to lose the timezone anyway.

I also think that parsing via `XMLGregorianCalendar` is better than with `DatatypeConverter.parseDate` via `Calendar` since `XMLGregorianCalendar` is much closer to the lexical value of `xsd:date`. What you need for `LocalDate` is just year, month and day so it's reasonable to prefer the shortest path to these values.

Comment: So my first example would loose timezone information, despite the fact its being converted to a `ZonedDateTime` first and then to a `LocalDate` (which presumably the ZonedDateTime has been coverted to a LocalDateTime first)?

Comment: @Cheetah `LocalDate` [does not store or represent a time or time-zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), period. So of course you lose time zone if you ultimately convert to `LocalDate`, no matter which results you may have had on the way there.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. My question is actually incorrect. My question should be: "How best should I pull out the date component from an xsd:date storing in a LocalDate object?"

Comment: @Cheetah I did answer this question, didn't I?